# c# get all childs of a array with specified name

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, deserialization

My question is clear. I want to get specified items(only value of name 'name') in this json array;

https://i.hizliresim.com/o6Z0Wb.png < Example ('result' section is was supposed to be in the previous circle.);

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":[
{"name":"VALUE_I_WANT_TO_GET1","Created":"2017-06-06T01:22:35.727"},  
{"name":"VALUE_I_WANT_TO_GET2","Created":"2017-06-06T01:22:35.727"},  
{"name":"VALUE_I_WANT_TO_GET3","Created":"2017-06-06T01:22:35.727"},  
{"name":"VALUE_I_WANT_TO_GET4","Created":"2017-06-06T01:22:35.727"}
]}
```

As you can see... this is a clear question. and my code is (I think it should be something like this) ;

```
        var json = wc.DownloadString("website/url");
        JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
        var test = (string)data["result"][/*I want to get all values with name 'name'*/]["name"];
```

**I did it with this code, you can use it :)**

```
        JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);

        for (int i = 0; i <= data["result"].Count()-1; i++)
        {
            var test = (string)data["result"][i]["name"];
            listBox1.Items.Add(test);
        }
```

Comment: Please show sample json..

Comment: I edited question

Comment: What type is `json_array` and which framework do you use for the deserialisation?

Comment: I used Newtonsoft.json nugget

Comment: Simply deserialize your data into some .NET-datatype and then use a select-query that select the first 227 elements: `myList.Take(227).Select(x => x.data)`.

Comment: how can I do that? I am new to c#

Comment: I did not want this.this code. this does not specify a child name.

Comment: What is a child-name here? You want only those entries with a given value within `data`? Or just those that are created at a specific date?

Comment: I want to get values with named 'data' . with 0 to 227 values (OR ALL VALUES OF CHİLDS NAMED "DATA")

Comment: So in your example only the first entry: `{"data":"value_to_get","Created":"2017-06-06T01:22:35.727"}`?

Comment: I want to get all values of named "data" child. the value is value_to_get as you see!

Comment: any helps? this is simple!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code:

```
void Main()
{
    // create array
    DataFromJSON[] data = new UserQuery.DataFromJSON[3];
    data[0] = new DataFromJSON() { Data = "val0", Created = DateTime.Now };
    data[1] = new DataFromJSON() { Data = "val1", Created = DateTime.Now };
    data[2] = new DataFromJSON() { Data = "val2", Created = DateTime.Now };

    var values = from x in data
                 select x.Data;

    values.Dump();

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class DataFromJSON
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set;}
}
```

Here#s a picture of the results, using LinqPad. The line `values.Dump()` calls an extension method defined by LinqPad to output the object it is attached to to the 'Results' window below the code windor.

[image: LinqPad5 resuts]

Comment: Sorry but my code is;
                var json = wc.DownloadString("https://site/JSON_DATA");
                JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
                var test = (string)data["result"][0-226]["NAME_TO_GET_VALUE"]
                textBox7.Text = test;

Answer (score 0):

First you have to de-serialize your json into your type:

```
MyType results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(json_array);
```

where `MyType` is something like this:

```
class MyType
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<AnotherType> results { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
class AnotherType
{
    public string data { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Now get the first 227 elements from it and select its `data`:

```
var data = myInstance.results.Take(227).Select(x => x.data);
```

Comment: NO, I want to take 227 childs with a SPECİFİED NAME like: deserialized_Json["results"][0-227]["SPECİFİED_NAME_FOR_GET_VALUES"];

Answer (score 0):

There's a neat trick Visual studio can do for you. First, copy a sample of the json you're expecting to query, Open a new C# file, and select `Edit` -> `Paste Special` -> `Paste JSON as classes`.
**BOOM!** Here are the classes you'll need, you should just give them meaningful names.

Next, you can desiralize the Json like so:

```
var myInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeJson<MyClass>(jsonString);
```

That'll give you an instance of the root object, with the data saved in an array inside it.

EDIT:

To select the values, you can do something like this (after you deserialize the data in the line above):

```
myInstance.Array.Select(x => x.name).ToList();
```

That would give a list containing only the strings in the name property of all your entires.

Comment: please look the picture added to question.

Comment: @Radagast - Something isn't clear to me, are the all the instances in the data of the same type? Or does the array contains multiple types? That is, Are you looking for all the values of the property `name`, or from all the instances in the array, you're looking for those that *contains* the property `name` (and the other contain no such property).

Comment: read this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468642/c-sharp-get-all-childs-of-a-array-with-specified-name/46469888#46469888

Comment: Yes, all instances same type, and I am looking for all the values of the property 'name'